# What is wrong in my LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, pdo

I'm trying to import a CSV file into MySQL database but it didn't work.

I have 5 columns in my database:

> id , userID, movieID, rate, timestamp

And in my CSV file I have only 4 columns separated by two colons '::'.
This is the sample data:

> 1::1193::5::978300760

This is my query

> $query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$uploadfile'          INTO TABLE rating_table
>             FIELDS TERMINATED BY '::'           LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'            (
>   userID, movieID, rate, timestamp)";

And I'm using `PDO_MySQL` this is the additional code so that you can understand.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

try{
        if($stmt->execute()){
                echo "Sucessful importing of CSV file into the MySQL database!";
            }

    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error importing of CSV file into the MySQL database!";
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
echo "</p>";
```

I've tried many times but when I've checked in my database, it is still empty.
I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, can you help me? Thanks!

This is the **error** I've got.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\php\upload_file.php:57 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\php\upload_file.php(57): PDOStatement->execute()
>   1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\php\upload_file.php on line 57

This is my **connection** settings:

> $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=movie','root', '',
>       array(
>           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8",
>           PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
>           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
>           PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => TRUE
>           ));

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar, That's my problem, I don't get any error.

Comment: Can you run the statement by hand in a mysql session and get it to work with a local file?

Comment: You have 5 fields in your SQL, but only 4 columns in the file.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes Sir do you think that is causing the problem?

Comment: It could be. What are you trying to set `@count` to?

Comment: Hmm, what happened to `@count` in your question?

Comment: @Harvey, please take a look at my answer, you might need additional inits, like `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => TRUE`, post an error output after setting `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`.

Comment: @Barmar, Sir sorry, I've already edited my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In order to see error messages on your output, just initialize your PDO with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, something like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db_host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db_name'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'],
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8",
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));
```

Afterwards you will be able to see the error. Post it in an update and I/we will be able to help you out!

#### EDIT 1:

Take a look at the manual on [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

You might also need:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => TRUE
```

> Note, this constant can only be used in the driver_options array when
>   constructing a new database handle.

#### EDIT 2:

According to [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html), MySQL must be compiled with `--enable-local-infile`:

> You MUST have compiled PHP using the full path to MySQL, otherwise it
>   will use it's internal handlers, which don't work with the "new" LOAD
>   DATA.
>
> --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql (assuming your MySQL is located here)
>
> You MUST start the MySQL daemon with the option '--local-infile=1'

Or enabling it, by adding to your `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
local-infile=1

[mysqld]
local-infile=1
```

Restart `mysqld` afterwards, by running `service mysqld restart`.

#### EDIT 3:

Quotes are for string literals, back-ticks for columns and tables names. Escape a variable properly. Change your query to:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE ' . $uploadfile . ' INTO TABLE `rating_table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '::' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ( `userID`, `movieID`, `rate`, `timestamp`)";
```

#### EDIT 4:

This error is normally caused when you have multiple queries `open` at the same time. For example, you call `fetch()`, but you don't call it until it's finished, and then you try to execute a second query.

Normally, the solution to this problem is to call `closeCursor()` [PHP: PDOStatement::closeCursor - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php).  Try calling that:

```
/* The following call to closeCursor() may be required by some drivers */
$stmt->closeCursor();

/* Now we can execute the second statement */
$otherStmt->execute();
```

and see if that changes anything for you.

#### EDIT 5:

Try using other syntax for escaping variable. Use the following:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
       LOAD DATA INFILE 
          '" . $uploadfile . "' 
       INTO TABLE 
          `rating_table`
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY 
          '::' 
       LINES TERMINATED BY 
          '\n' ( `userID`, `movieID`, `rate`, `timestamp`)
");
$stmt->execute();
```

#### EDIT 6:

PDO placeholders can only be used for values, and not database, table or column names! I think the error is coming from using `'::'`. Change your data delimiter in your files from `'::'` to, let's say `'.'`.

As quick workaround for checking you could use your query directly without prepare:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("
       LOAD DATA INFILE 
          '" . $uploadfile . "' 
       INTO TABLE 
          `rating_table`
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY 
          '::' 
       LINES TERMINATED BY 
          '\n' ( `userID`, `movieID`, `rate`, `timestamp`)
");
```

If it doesn't work try changing data delimiter or try escaping your existing delemiter (`::`) somehow.

Comment: Sir, I've already edited my post and include there the error. Thanks!

Comment: What about setting `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => TRUE`, have you tried that?

Comment: Sir, I have edited the error in my post and I think I'm close enough in solving it.

Comment: @Harvey, please take a look at `EDIT 3`, this might solve you problem! If it doesn't work try removing `' . . '` completely.

Comment: I tried to insert single-quote in `$uploadfile` So it becomes like this `$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$uploadfile' INTO TABLE `rating_table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '::' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ( userID, movieID, rate, timestamp)"; . It gives a different error from the one that I've posted above.

Comment: Here's the error. `Error importing of CSV file into the MySQL database!Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.`

Comment: What do you use after `$query`?

Comment: This line `$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);` comes after the query.

Comment: And then..? And then..?

Comment: Sir, I've only one statement. This is my only statement `$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);` following the query. After that the `try catch` statement.

Comment: That is wired as you don't execute your query? No wonder you get an error. Run either instead `$stmt = $dbh->query($query);` or better add afterwards `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: Yes Sir I have this on the try, `  if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "Sucessful importing of CSV file into the MySQL database!";
   }`

Comment: Try removing that `try` and `catch` stuff. Just run it normally. You don't need it in every query. You don't need it at all, I think!

Comment: Take a look at `EDIT 5` and post what happens when you `echo $uploadfile`, please!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Ahm Sir I've tried your EDIT 5 and I echoed the `uploadfile`. This is the output of `uploadfile`-> `C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\uploads\movieratings.dat` and below is the error, and the same error Sir.

Comment: This is the error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\php\upload_file.php:67 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\php\upload_file.php(67): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\php\upload_file.php on line 67`

Comment: Sure, I see! What do you get if you do: `echo readfile($uploadfile);`

Comment: It returns the content of the file. Like this -> `1::1193::5::978300760 1::661::3::978302109 1::914::3::978301968 1::3408::4::978300275 1::2355::5::978824291 1::1197::3::978302268 1::1287::5::978302039 1::2804::5::978300719 1::594::4::978302268 ...`

Comment: Okay...but how will I be able to change the delimiter on my files? I've only downloaded it on the movielens dataset.

Comment: You can go with `$data  = str_replace('::', '.', file_get_contents($uploadfile));`

Comment: I've done EDIT 6, replace the '::' with '.'and use query directly without prepare but the same error.

Comment: You could try `"::"` but I'm not sure! Double check your query! Try to re-saving your file to make sure the encoding is set correctly on the file. It's hard to debug without access to executable code! It could be anything!

Comment: Okay I understand. I think what can I do now is to look for other ways in saving CSV file or importing it into MySQL. Thank you for your help Sir. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Pay attention to reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `LOCAL` keyword in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement.

`LOCAL` means that the file you are loading from is located on the client and not on the server. When I just tried this, with your table and file, it worked fine.

```
> cat infile.csv 
1::1193::5::978300760

> mysql
mysql > create table ratings (
    id int primary key auto_increment, 
    userID int, 
    movieID int, 
    rate int, 
    ts long);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql > LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'infile.csv' INTO TABLE ratings FIELDS TERMINATED BY '::' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ( userID, movieID, rate, ts);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql > select * from ratings;
+----+--------+---------+------+-----------+
| id | userID | movieID | rate | ts        |
+----+--------+---------+------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |    1193 |    5 | 978300760 |
+----+--------+---------+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've added the `LOCAL` keyword but I think your close. Ahm to elaborate I have this code `$uploaddir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\uploads\movie';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);` and I used `$uploadfile` in my query. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @Harvey did you confirm that your $uploadfile actually exists at that location with file_exists?

Comment: @eis, Yes Sir, I've verified, checked it using `file_exists` and Yes it existed.

Comment: Try to put it somewhere simple, like c:\testfile.csv, to start with. That way you can eliminate problems you do in php or problems with mysql. Also try to run the command using normal mysql client.

Comment: I tried what you've said put it in my local disk C, and modified the path to be able to read it in the local disk C but the same error I've got Sir.