# import csv file with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in symfony 1.4

Tags: mysql, csv, import, symfony-1.4

I need to fill several of tables with CSV files. I tried to use a loop that do insert with each row but a file with 65,000 records take me more then 20 min.

I want to use the MySQL command `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, but I received this message :

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\apps\backend\modules\member\actions\actions.class.php on line 112

After a little research, I understand there is need to change one of the security parameters of the PDO (`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE`) to true.

In symfony2, you need to change it at config.yml of your app, but I can't find it on symfony 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to understand the question (or questions?!).

If you need to optimize the `INSERT` queries you should probably batch them at a single `INSERT` query or a few ones, but definitely not for each row. Besides, the `INSERT` query in MySQL will be always slow especially for a large amount of data inserted, also depends on indexing, engine and schema structure of the DB.

About the second question, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072614/what-is-wrong-in-my-load-data-infile-syntax), maybe it will help.